# listen.owner & listen.group not taken into account

Tags: php-fpm

I'm trying to change the owner/group of the PHP-FPM socket file.

My `www.conf` contains:

```
[www]

...

listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen.owner = ben
listen.group = ben
listen.mode = 0660
```

**Upon restarting php-fpm, `www.sock` is still owned by `root:root`.**

If I change the socket file location, or the `listen.mode`, the socket file changes accordingly. However, `listen.owner` and `listen.group` seem to be blatantly ignored.

**Why is that?**

Comment: Please post your full php-fpm config to pastebin, since some config directives can override each-other.

Comment: Thank you, reviewing it while posting to pastebin made me actually read every configuration option, and I found out about `listen.acl_users`. See my answer below!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it. The issue was `listen.acl_users` (emphasis mine):

> When POSIX Access Control Lists are supported you can set them using
> these options, value is a comma separated list of user/group names.
> **When set, listen.owner and listen.group are ignored.**

**Solution**: comment out this line:

```ini
;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on that, this saved me some time. Another lesson in reading ALL the documentation for what you're doing!